# Starting a section with a number

Tags: structure, sections, routes

I have a section of type structure where I need the url to be /5minutes. I cannot make this work (note that I have changed the handle to fiveminutes. But everything I would like to be 5minutes. I even tried setting a route for 5minutes. My question then is this. Is is simply not possible to begin a route or section with a numerical value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A section can't have a handle that [starts with a number](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/validators/HandleValidator.php#L22), but there is nothing stopping you from using `fiveminutes` for the section's handle and setting the section's URL Format to `5minutes/{slug}`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and it doesn't seem to work. Does the entry template need to be fiveminutes/_entry as well? or can it be 5minutes/_entry?  Oh, I should let you know I guess that I am using a section type of Structure.

Comment: Doesn't matter for the entry template as long as what you put in the CP matches what's on the file system. Just did a test locally with a structured section and it works as expected for me.

Comment: Okay, looks like i may have sent you down the wrong path. After further testing I am able to get entries to render. But when I hit what is should be /5minutes it is failing to render the index.html template in the 5minutes directory.

Comment: I was able to fix the /5minutes index.html issue by creating a route. Not sure if this is the proper way to make this work, but it works.